# Windows 7 Unable to Focus

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, focus, window-focus

I've been trying to dig around to see if I can find this issue to no avail. Doing anything in windows 7 to get the focus of a window besides clicking on the window or using <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> has no effect. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will not bring anything to focus, neither will clicking on the icon on my taskbar. It highlights the icon on my taskbar in orange as if something is urgent on it, but won't take focus. I've double checked that nothing is always on top, and indeed, nothing's actually stealing the focus - I'm just stuck unable to take the focus when I need to.

I do hope someone can help, and sorry if this is a duplicate question, I couldn't quite find the same issue anywhere around here.

Comment: I have never seen this issue before, until recently.  Suddenly, I have seen this problem as well.  I wonder if it is a Windows update or an AntiVirus update that has a problem.  Are you using 32 or 64-bit Windows?  Which AntiVirus are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It is a very rare problem, I had never heard something like that...
I don't think it's a hardware or malware problem, I think that it was by a registry edit that went wrong.
Try this:
Runs a command prompt with administrator privileges.
Start Menu > All Programs > Accessories > Command Prompt (right click, run as administrator, Yes) 
writes "**sfc /scannow**" (without the quotes) and wait untill the proces is completed (a few minutes)

The System File Checker (sfc) is a utility in Microsoft Windows that allows users to scan for and restore corruptions in Windows system files...

Remember that you can paste text in the Command Prompt, by clicking on the program's icon > edit > paste

```
sfc /scannow
```

I hope it has helped you...